# How to gets users EMAIL by their USERNAME

Tags: user-meta, email, plugin-gravity-forms, username

If I have a users username, is it possible to take that and echo their email address instead?

I have a field in Gravity Forms that has the assigned user to that job. I have added some code that echos the value of the input which is their username. How do I take that value and transform it into an echo that is their email instead? Here is the code I am working with:

```
    <?php 
    $lead_id = $entry_slug_esc;
    $lead = RGFormsModel::get_lead( $lead_id ); 
    $form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta( $lead['form_id'] ); 

    $values= array();

    foreach( $form['fields'] as $field ) {

        $values[$field['id']] = array(
            'value' => $lead[ $field['id'] ],
        );
    }
    ?>
    <div><?php echo $values[52]['value']; ?></div>
    // <?php echo $values[52]['value']; ?> is the username.  Instead of echoing that I want it to be that users email.
```

Note: I can't just change the value of that field to their email@address because I am also using it as a search param and it does not work with the @ in the url structure.

Comment: Once you have the username, use `get_user_by('login', 'username')`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/ . Be sure they know to enter their `user_login` rather than `user_nicename` or `display_name`, and be careful where you show this type of information since it could be used by hackers to try to discover valid usernames and emails on your site.

Comment: and the winner is https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/